# Command that returns exit code still returning 0 when using "command 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/file.log"

Tags: scripting, shell, pipe

I'm running a script that executes a command and save the output to a file in /var/log. After that, it gets the exit code and execute another command based on an if/else condition. The problem is:  *2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/file.log* always returns 0, no matter the real exit code from the command.

How to work around this problem?

Piece of the code:

```
rdiff-backup --force /localdir external.domain"::/backups/externaldir 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/file.log
e="$(echo $?)"
if [ "$e" == "0" ]; then
        echo "`date` Done." 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/file.log
else
        echo "`date` Fail!" 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/file.log            
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the exit code of a pipe is the exit code of the *last* stage of a pipe, and tee never fails :)

This can be solved different ways depending on your shell.   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another collects many answers.

Comment: Would you care to suggest one of the ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Your link helped me a lot. I'm using _set -o pipefail_ now. With this, if a command returns false | true, it will return false. [(Chris' answer)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14282/298547)